# Calculate days to be excluded based on a given date

Tags: t-sql

I want to calculate days to be excluded where the weekday of given date is on Friday, Saturday & Sunday.

I am using below query to calculate days to be excluded based on *weekday* for a given date.

```
SELECT 2 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') + 5 - 2) / 5) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') / 7
SELECT 2 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-30') + 5 - 2) / 5) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-30') / 7
SELECT 2 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-31') + 5 - 2) / 5) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-31') / 7
```

Actual result should be 2,1,0 respectively for the above. But I am getting 2,3,0.
Can anyone suggest how to get it

Thank you

Comment: can you please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

one way can be to directly check and for Friday, Saturday and Sunday and assign values:

```
    select case when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') = 6 then 2 
            when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') = 7 then 1 
            when DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') = 1 then 0 
            else 0 end as days_to_Excluede
```

but if this is not your requirement then you can wait for some other answers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the days till Sunday? Correct me if I'm wrong. If that's the case I think this will do, otherwise could you explain a bit more:

```
SELECT 7 - CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-29') - 1 END
SELECT 7 - CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-30') = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-30') - 1 END
SELECT 7 - CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-31') = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2021-10-31') - 1 END
```

EDIT:
Since you don't want to use CASE here it is:

```
SELECT 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(dd, -1,'2021-10-29'))
```

Comment: Can suggest without using case statement?

Comment: Everything is good but while adding 0 days the below result is wrong 
`SELECT 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(dd, -1,'2021-10-30')) `. It should be 2021-10-30 but getting 2021-10-31. And one morething if add 12 days to '2021-10-30' it should show '2021-11-16' but showing '2021-11-12'. Can you please check

Comment: If you tell me exactly what do you want to achieve I might be able to help. But as I mention in my answer I thought you want to count the days till Sunday. In your example you mentioned that the expected result from the calculation on date `2021-10-30` should be `1` which is what my solution returns!? Now you're saying you add days somewhere and I have no idea what you're trying to do. If I assume correctly you want to add number of "work days" to a specific date?! If so, your logic is wrong and you should update your question and explain exactly what you want to achieve.